# In an Apigee API Proxy, Unable to route to new target even after rewriting “target.url” via a JavaScript policy

Tags: javascript, api, proxy, apigee

I have a node.js application(deployed using Hosted Target) (with query parameter). What I am trying to do is, When I hit my current url I want to redirect it to a new url (my cloud function url). I have used a javascript policy for it. The script is something like:

```
var url = 'https://..xyz.com';

context.setVariable("target.url",url);
```

I have my javascript policy on Targetendpoint Response flow.

But I am getting an error:

```
Cannot GET /..xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

This Apigee Community post is about this use case, albeit not within the JS context: https://community.apigee.com/questions/31202/how-to-dynamically-set-target-url.html

Specifically see: "Make sure that this is done in the Target Endpoint as this variable's scope is restricted."